# how can i set the context_info sql statement from Devforce IdeaBlade app

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, devforce

I need to set the Context_info from my winforms application so that i can notify the database not to run a trigger if my application is saving a record vs a legacy app which needs to run the trigger. Everything i have read says it needs to be set using a data context.

In my application i am using an entity manager. How can i set the data context using an entity manager instead of a datacontext. I just want the trigger to know that it is my app running and saving the data on which the trigger is set

i want to do like the follow. "set context_info '0x1234'

at the start of the trigger i check to see if the context_info is set and dont run the trigger. The legacy does not set the context_info.

Answer (score 3):

We needed to do this same thing for our app.  As Kim mentioned, there is a lot of information in the Dev Force forums.  You can find a full explanation of what we did [in this forum post](http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=3855&PID=15476&title=value-cannot-be-null-getting-ientityqueryt-when-using-usepersistentdbconnectionpersession#15476) but I'll reproduce the important parts here for reference...

We had a similar requirement in our application.  In our case, we needed to call a custom stored procedure every time a DB connection was opened - the procedure would 'mark' the connection with what user was currently active because we have lots of triggers that need to know the current user (we use context_info to accomplish this 'marking').

We were able to handle this with the help of the [EF Provider Wrapper Toolkit](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/) (also seems to be on [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/CommunityEFProviderWrappers.EFProviderWrapperToolkit) now).  That basically lets you inject your own logic into various ADO.NET objects - so at the very lowest level of database access.  We then made our own custom DbConnection class that DevForce/EntityFramework end up using.  It was actually pretty easy and has given us a lot of nice 'hooks' into the lowest level of database access that has come in handy a lot.

Here is some sample code for our custom DbConnection class that shows the kinds of things you can accomplish:

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom implementation of a wrapper to <see cref="DbConnection"/>.
/// Allows custom behavior at the connection level.
/// </summary>
internal class CustomDbConnection : DbConnectionWrapper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Opens a database connection with the settings specified by 
    /// the <see cref="P:System.Data.Common.DbConnection.ConnectionString"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Open()
    {
        base.Open();

        //After the connection has been opened, do our logic to prep the connection
        SetContextInfo();

        //...and we do some other stuff not relevant to this discussion
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Closes the connection to the database. This is the preferred method of closing any open connection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.Data.Common.DbException">
    /// The connection-level error that occurred while opening the connection.
    /// </exception>
    public override void Close()
    {
        //Before closing, we do some cleanup with the connection to make sure we leave it clean
        //   for the next person that might get it....

        base.Close();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Attempts to set context_info to the current connection if the user is 
    /// logged in to our application.
    /// </summary>
    private void SetContextInfo()
    {
        //See if a user is logged in
        var user = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as OurCustomUserType;

        //If not, we don't need to do anything - this is probably a very early call in the application
        if (user == null)
            return;

        //Create the ADO.NET command that will call our stored procedure
        var cmd = CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "p_prepare_connection_for_use";

        //Set the parameters based on the currently logged in user
        cmd.CreateParameter("as_session_id", user.SessionID, null, DbType.Guid);
        cmd.CreateParameter("ai_user_sid", user.UserID, null, DbType.Int32);

        //Run the SP
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

In EF6 and beyond, there might be a cleaner way to intercept database calls....but this approach has been working great for years.

Answer (score 0):

Although the [IdeaBlade forums](http://www.ideablade.com/forum/forum_topics.asp?FID=54&title=devforce-2012) have been closed to new activity, they are still searchable and do often contain helpful answers and information regarding DevForce issues.  In this case, if you search for context_info there you will find some useful threads.  One in particular shows how to use either the [EF Provider Wrapper Toolkit](http://efwrappers.codeplex.com/) or [EF 6 DbCommandInterceptor](http://satalketo.com/2013/12/logging-sql-queries-mvc/) to work with the context_info.  These do not require a DbContext.