# How to use IDbCommandInterceptor to modify SQL when CommandType is StoredProcedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework 6 and would like to set `CONTEXT_INFO` before any modifications to data, so my audit triggers can log which user made modifications. It seems this should be possible using `IDbCommandInterceptor` to change the `CommandText` that will be executed, something like the code below. But if the `DbCommand.CommandType == CommandType.StoredProcedure` then it doesn't like this, because it expects the `CommandText` will be *just* the procedure name, and throws an error if I prefix it with my extra SQL.

```
public class SetContextInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{

    public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
    {
        command.CommandText = GetSqlForSetContextInfo() + command.CommandText;
    }

     // ... other interface methods similar

    private string GetSqlForSetContextInfo()
    {
        var currentUsername = Thread.CurrentPrincipal != null && Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity != null
            ? Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
            : null;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentUsername))
        {
            return "";
        }

        return "EXEC usp_setUserContext '" + currentUsername.Replace('\'', ' ') + "'; ";
    }

}
```

In particular the Parameters aren't in the `CommandText` in this case (i.e. CommandText contains just the stored procedure name), so I don't want to get into the messy business of doing string manipulation for the parameters. Is there an easy way of handling this case?

Here's some other articles on achieving similar things with `CONTEXT_INFO`. It seems like there's lots of variations on this theme but no agreed way of doing it, and many techniques were pre-EF6 so didn't have the `IDbCommandInterceptor`  option.

- [Logging every data change with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295710/logging-every-data-change-with-entity-framework)
- [how can i set the context_info sql statement from Devforce IdeaBlade app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24168904/how-can-i-set-the-context-info-sql-statement-from-devforce-ideablade-app)
- http://forum.ideablade.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=3855&PID=15476&title=value-cannot-be-null-getting-ientityqueryt-when-using-usepersistentdbconnectionpersession#15476
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/19065701-6efa-4740-acca-b0e5312ca4f4/am-i-leaking-dbcontext-objects-by-handling-statechange?forum=adodotnetentityframeworkhttp://itq.nl/sql-azure-row-level-security-entity-framework/
- http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2013/09/13/entity-framework-and-user-context/
- http://davecallan.com/passing-userid-delete-trigger-entity-framework

**UPDATE**

I'm guessing because [it's not possible to get the 'SQL' that's executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356467/from-net-can-i-get-the-full-sql-string-generated-by-a-sqlcommand-object-with-s) when CommandType = StoredProcedure that it's not possible to manipulate it. The option that occurs to me (for my scenario where I want to set CONTEXT_INFO) is to grab the `command.Connection` and execute a separate command to set CONTEXT_INFO. I'm not sure how well that'll work, e.g. if connection isn't already open then I have to open it myself.

[From .NET can I get the full SQL string generated by a SqlCommand object (with SQL Parameters)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356467/from-net-can-i-get-the-full-sql-string-generated-by-a-sqlcommand-object-with-s)

Comment: *In particular the Parameters aren't in the CommandText in this case* I don't understand what you mean by that. It would help to see how you run the stored procedure.

Comment: `command.CommandText` looks like `"usp_EmployeeUpdate"` (i.e. it contains just the proc name). `command.Parameters` contains the parameter names and values. In my particular example the proc is called by Entity Framework, autogenerated code, but could be any other case where you use `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`.

Comment: e.g. `return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("MyEntities.usp_EmployeeUpdate", idParameter, billingIdParameter,  ... <other params> ... );`

Answer (score 0):

As per my UPDATE above, I decided this isn't possible.